# Sql update table with joined sums of other tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to reduce storage with packages included in sold products.

Products can have different amounts of same packages and invoice can have different amounts of products in separate lines. Action should be performed against certain invoiceID.

Simplified tables (summary is not column, just added to ease up calculation):

```
Inv_rows                
InvID   ProdID  Qty     *Summary*
999     100     2       *100 = 10*
999     101     2       *101 = 2*
999     102     2       *102 = 2*
999     103     2       *103 = 10*
999     100     8       
999     103     8       
                
Pack_to_prod                
ProdID  PackID  Qty     
100     A       2       *A = 20*
100     B       1       *B = 10*
101     A       1       *A = 2*
101     B       1       *B = 2*
102     A       3       *A = 6*
103     B       2       *B = 20*
                
Storage             
ItemID  Qty         
A       100             *A = 28*
B       100             *B = 32*
                
                
**Desired Result**              
Storage             
ItemID  Qty         
A       72              *(100-28)*  
B       68              *(100-32)*
```

What I have tried is:

```
UPDATE Storage
     SET Storage.Qty = Storage.Qty - 
    (SELECT SUM (Inv_rows.Qty * Pack_to_prod.Qty) FROM Inv_rows
         WHERE Inv_rows.ProdID IN (SELECT ProdID FROM Pack_to_prod 
     WHERE Pack_to_prod.PackID=Storage.ItemID) AND Inv_rows.InvId = 999
    )
     FROM Inv_rows, Storage, Pack_to_prod
     WHERE Inv_rows.ProdID = Pack_to_prod.ProdID
     AND Pack_to_prod.PackID = Storage.ItemID
     AND Inv_rows.InvID = 999
```

But the problem is the 'IN' since it doesn't match the rows but I can't use '=' as 'where' results more than one line.

Then I tried to simplify it for myself (as I'm not a professional) with a select clause to understand what exactly needs to be done..

```
SELECT 
Pack_to_prod.PackID AS PackageID,
Inv_rows.ProdID AS ProductID,
Inv_rows.Qty AS ProductQty, 
Pack_to_prod.Qty AS PackageQtyPerProduct, 
Inv_rows.Qty*Pack_to_prod.Qty AS PackageTotal, 
Storage.Qty AS StorageQty, 
Storage.Qty - (Inv_rows.Qty * Pack_to_prod.Qty) AS NewStorageQty   
FROM Pack_to_prod,Inv_rows,Storage 
WHERE Inv_rows.ProdID = Pack_to_prod.ProdID 
AND Pack_to_prod.PackID = Storage.ItemID 
AND Inv_rows.InvID = 999
GROUP BY Inv_rows.ProdID, Pack_to_prod.PackID, Pack_to_prod.Qty, Storage.Qty, Inv_rows.Qty
```

Which results as simple list showing the problem why they can't be just summed up:

```
PackageID   ProductID   ProductQty PackageQtyPerProduct PackageTotal StorageQty NewStorageQty  
A           100         2          2                    4            100        96
A           100         8          2                    16           100        84
B           100         2          1                    2            100        98
B           100         8          1                    8            100        92
A           101         2          1                    2            100        98
B           101         2          1                    2            100        98
A           102         2          3                    6            100        94
B           103         2          2                    4            100        96
B           103         8          2                    16           100        84
```

But can't figure out how to make it run 'line by line' so that each 'Pack_to_prod.Qty' would be handled separately.

Any help in right direction appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems like some aggregations and joins.  To get the *changes* in values, then:

```
select pp.packid, sum(p.qty * pp.qty) as new_qty
from (select ir.prodid, sum(qty) as qty
      from inv_rows ir
      group by ir.prodid
     ) p join
     Pack_to_prod pp
     on pp.prodid = p.prodid
group by pp.packid;
```

You can then use this in an `update`:

```
update s
    set s.qty = s.qty - pp.new_qty
    from storage s join
         (select pp.packid, sum(p.qty * pp.qty) as new_qty
          from (select ir.prodid, sum(qty) as qty
                from inv_rows ir
                group by ir.prodid
               ) p join
               Pack_to_prod pp
               on pp.prodid = p.prodid
          group by pp.packid
         ) pp
         on pp.packid = s.itemid;
```

Answer (score 0):

This was explained very well.  The SQL code is user older coding conventions (such as JOIN conditions in the WHERE clause, instead of FROM) and isn't organized into subqueries properly.  All the pieces are present though.  I think something like this is what you're looking for.

```
with
inv_cte(ProdID, sum_qty) as (
    select ProdID, sum(Qty)
    from Inv_rows
    group by ProdID),
pack_cte(PackID, prod_qty) as (
    select pp.PackID, sum(pp.Qty*ic.sum_qty)
    from Pack_to_prod pp
         join inv_cte ic on pp.ProdID=ic.ProdID
    group by pp.PackID)
select s.ItemID, s.Qty-p.prod_qty as ResultQty
from Storage s
     join pack_cte p on s.ItemID=p.PackID;
```

Update statement

```
with
inv_cte(ProdID, sum_qty) as (
    select ProdID, sum(Qty)
    from Inv_rows
    group by ProdID),
pack_cte(PackID, prod_qty) as (
    select pp.PackID, sum(pp.Qty*ic.sum_qty)
    from Pack_to_prod pp
         join inv_cte ic on pp.ProdID=ic.ProdID
    group by pp.PackID)
update s
  set Qty=Qty-p.prod_qty
from Storage s
     join pack_cte p on s.ItemID=p.PackID;
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried to copy your code and run it but got some error. I don't understand yet how it works so I'm not able to fix - should I be able to run it like written above?

Comment: The question lists 4 simplified tables.  If those are a,b,c,d then the CTE inv_cte in intended to accomplish a.  The CTE pack_cte to accomplish b&c.  The final select to accomplish d.

Comment: I will try to google CTE (common table expression) first. I will get back after I understand your reply.

Error was:
Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 8
Column 'Pack_to_prod.Qty' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 8
Column 'inv_cte.sum_qty' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: Yes, now it gives the result I'm looking for. Now I just need to figure out how to put it in update statement. Thanks!